# Why is my BizTalk SSO settings not showing in SSO Administrator or the SSO client Utility?

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

I have installed several application on a BizTalk 2020 server using BTDF 5.8  where I used to the application settings in the deployment to update any config for the BizTalk applications.

My own account is part of the SSO admin group and I use the in proc host account to install the apps into the BizTalk server. The proc host account is also part of the SSO admin group.

When I view the SSO using the admin or client utility no apps are shown. I also downloaded and run the [BizTalk-Server-SSO-Application-Configuration-Tool](https://github.com/BizTalkCommunity/BizTalk-Server-SSO-Application-Configuration-Tool). The tool also showed no  current installed applications, but was able to add an application with it config.

But ideally I would like to view and edit current config as I am currently getting an error on a server with incorrect value.

Is there another tool to view and edit settings or am I missing something that must be enabled.

Comment: I added up writing the error to file with the parameters used to request the SSO setting. Then using the tool above, I added the missing setting or updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing to get around the problem above. I added a statement to write the error received from trying to read the SSO setting to file with the parameters used to request the SSO setting. Then using the tool above, I added the missing setting or updated it.